# find an item in xml file

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, selectsinglenode

i have a xml file like below

```
<root>
 <Month name="Jan"  index="1">
      <Day index="2">
         <event> sample 1</event>
      </Day>
       <Day index="3">
         <event> sample 2 </event>
      </Day>
  </Month>

<Month name="Feb"  index="2">
      <Day index="5">
         <event> sample 3 </event>
      </Day>
       <Day index="2">
         <event> sample 4 </event>
      </Day>
  </Month>
</root>
```

how can i find special month and day event ?
for example i want getting "sample 2" when month is 1 and day is 2

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("EventsXML.xml");
XmlNode even= doc.SelectSingleNode("/root/Month[@index='1'] |/root/Month/day[@index='2']");
string str=even.InnerXml.ToString();
```

Comment: Use LINQ to XML and XDocument.

Answer (score 2):

You need to modify your xpath to something like this:

```
XmlNode even= doc.SelectSingleNode("/root/Month[@index='1']/Day[@index='2']/event");
```

You can also use InnerText rather than InnerXml as you know the content is text, *or* you can modify the xPath to take this into account:

```
XmlNode even = doc.SelectSingleNode("/root/Month[@index='1']/Day[@index='2']/event/text()");
string str = even.Value;
```

Answer (score 2):

An XDocument (Linq-to-XML) answer:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(...);
var day = doc.Root
    .Descendants("Month")
    .Where(e => e.Attributes("index").Value == m)
    .Descendants("Day")
    .Where(e => e.Attributes("index").Value == d);
```

('m' and 'd' as string for simplicity)